# Edit the DataGrid after filter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `DataRowView`.

When I do any operations such as Insert/Delete/Copy/Paste/Undo/Redo, I manipulate the underlying DataSource.

Ex: When I have to paste data into a set of cells, I get their row and column indexes (the cell the context menu points to) and edit the DataSource. I store their previous values and their indexes to revert back when I do an "Undo" operation.

When I filter the grid, the view changes where as the DataSource remains the same. So, when I do a paste operation, the indexes I get don't match with the ones in the DataSource. I end up pasting in the wrong cells.

How can I manipulate the DataSource i.e get the actual indexes/data to do all the operations after filter is applied?

Comment: Do the edited values have some kind of unique id? In this case you could use the id to identify the item (row) which shall be rolled back. You would have to write a method like "GetRowIndexForID". As soon as you have your row index based on the id, you can perform your undo operation.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an ID :(

Comment: Could you create an Id on the unfiltered items for runtime used only? So the filtered items will still have the same id.

Comment: Can you post the code which you set as 'ItemsSource' on the DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood after reading your question. New record which appear after Item1 should apppear after Item1 in source collection too. This is not happening right now as index is differing which will of course differ.
As you have not posted code, so I have posted sample code below :

```
// new employee to add
            Employee empNew = new Employee() { Name = "New1", Address = "NewAdd1" };

// get corresponding item  in filtered view after which you want to insert
            Employee emp = (Employee)DgrdEmployees.SelectedItem;

// get true collection which is datasource
            ObservableCollection<Employee> sourceCol = (ObservableCollection<Employee>)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DgrdEmployees.ItemsSource).SourceCollection);

// find index of selected item after which we are inserting/pasting
            int trueIndex = sourceCol.IndexOf(emp);

// insert it at exact location in true unfiltered source collection
            sourceCol.Insert(trueIndex + 1, empNew);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the only way to go about it.